# Java messagebox does not pop up

Tags: java

I am new to Java and have below code when meeting criteria `tempTable.size() == 1` then messagebox will pop up, but it doesn't work and the code stops at the line `System.out.println("Print Message No search result");` Anyone can help me why the messagebox does not pop up?

```
public boolean Report()throws DocumentException, IOException {

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, LEFT_MARGIN, RIGHT_MARGIN, TOP_MARGIN, BOTTOM_MARGIN);

    PdfPTable tempTable = constructTable();
    System.out.println("Document size is " + tempTable.size());
    if (tempTable.size() == 1) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Print Message No search result");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Search Result");
                System.out.println("Finish Print Message No search result");

            }  catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println("throw exception on try show msgbox: "); 

            }


    }else{...}
```

Comment: Give us a runnable example that reproduces the issue. If I put the content of your try block in a main method and run it, the dialog is shown just fine.

Comment: Do neither `System.out.println("Finish Print Message No search result")` nor `System.out.println("throw exception on try show msgbox: ");` execute?

Comment: Instead of showing the messagebox, it pops up a "Blank Page" in the web UI and then stops - I think the issue may be on the Blank Page but I could not find the code related to the Blank Page that causing it pop up, I just want to simply pop up the messagebox even there is a Blank Page which maybe another bug I might not able to fix it, is there anyway to "force" pop up of the message box?

Comment: To Dhruv Murarka, none of the two printIn executed...